# Geometry interpretation on an algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Could somebody give me a snap of the geometric interpretation of this set ?$$\pi/2 \leq  \arg(z + 1 - i)^2 \leq  3\pi/2$$ and $$|z+3-i| < |z+i|$$

Comment: What is squared here $\arg(z + 1 - i)^2$?

Comment: arg on the regular basis mean the angle . This is the task which was given to me during my studies , so i think it is is able to compute .

Comment: Yes but the square? is this for the arg or for the number inside the brakets?

Comment: it is for the arg

Comment: Note that it would be much more logical to take the arg of $(z + 1- i)^2$ than taking the square of the argument of $(z + 1 - i)$, especially with the given limiting angles...

Comment: They are held at the same time , they are not seperated sets

Comment: The latter condition describes the points which are closer to the complex point $-3 + i$ than to the complex point $-i$. What would those be? (Hint: what's the geometric interpretation of the points which lie at the *same* distance from those two points?)

Comment: You might be right with that it is arg of (z + 1 - i)^2 if i were able to do that on my own i would have not posted it here , anyway i do know it is symetric line if we talk about second set , but we have not got there equation so i do not really know how to illustrate it

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\pi/2 \leq  \arg^2(w) \leq  3\pi/2 \iff \sqrt{\pi/2} \leq  \arg(w) \leq  \sqrt{3\pi/2}$$

represents all the complex number $w$ in the half plane $\Im(w)\ge 0$ contained between the lines $y=\tan(\sqrt{\pi/2})x$ and $y=\tan(\sqrt{3\pi/2})x$.

While $|z+3-i| < |z+i|$ represents the points which distance from $(3-i)=(3,-1)$ is less than the distance from $(-i)=(0,-1)$.

Comment: why did we go for tan(x)?

Comment: and it is rather not arg of

Comment: Yes the relation for arg is given by  $\sqrt{\pi/2} \leq  \arg(w) \leq  \sqrt{3\pi/2}$, by $\tan$ we can visualize the region in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite the first one as $$\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\arg(z+1-i)\leq\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

This is the region bounded between two part-lines from the point $-1+i$ at angles $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ to the real axis.

This region overlaps the area on one side of the perpendicular bisector of $-3+i$ and $-i$ on the side of $-3+i$

Comment: i know that , but what to do next ?

Comment: should we go for trygonometry form ? or something

Comment: i guess it will be the area limited by this angle from two sides like from the upper and lower bcs it is π/4 +2kπ and 3π/4 +2kπ and we will count for k = 0 and k = 1 since it has been arg(something)^2 and we will count our angles from the (-1,1)

Comment: but how to compute second set ?